# Как сравнить значения из соседних строк в отсортированном наборе?

Tags: sql, sql-server, оптимизация

Есть выборка вида:

```
Id Value
1 5
2 5
3 6
4 3
5 5
```

Мне нужно сравнить значения Value из строк с Id равными N и N+1 (соседними строками).
Т.е. для простоты считаем, что Id - непрерывная последовательность натуральных чисел.

Вопросы:

1) Как это лучше, а главное, оптимальней сделать?

2) Всё то же самое, но мне нужно сравнить значения N подряд идущих строк... Как это оптимальней сделать?

Comment: А CTE не подходит как оптимальное?

Comment: При чем здесь СТЕ?:) Как самоджойн? Можно - но это неэффективно. Меня интересует именно оптимальное решение.

Comment: Вам же надо пройти по строкам и для каждой следующей иметь доступ в предыдущей. Это можно сделать с помощью CTE, нет?

Comment: @Box, можно, но не оптимально. есть ещё LEAD и LAG, которые по идее для этого и заточены, но тоже медленно работают.

Comment: @pegoopik Еще есть first_value, last_value которые можно применить к окну шириной в 2 записи. Но если lag медленный, то любые оконные функции видимо так же будут медленными. А это возможно значит, что надо пересматривать вот ту "_Есть выборка вида_". И что значит сравнить N значений, т.е. вытянуть их в один список выборки что бы были рядом, что бы потом как с отдельными колонками с ними работать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну тут, собственно, какие варианты могут быть.

Если данные из соседних строк часто требуются, то думаю, оптимальнее всего будет выбрать и сохранить их в отдельный(-е) столбец(-цы), чтобы затем использовать.

Если вычислять на лету - то либо windowed функции, либо `join`-ы на себя:

```
select
    d.id, d.value,
    prev = lag(d.value) over (order by d.id)
from data d

select
    d.id, d.value,
    prev = d_lag.value
from data d
    left join data d_lag on d_lag.id = d.id - 1
```

Если используются оконные функции, то для оптимальной производительности желательно придерживаться т.н. POC (*Partitioning, Ordering, Coverage*) индексации. Т.е. в данном случае должен быть кластерный индекс по `Id`, либо некластерный покрывающий `index (Id) include (Value)`. При использовании `join`-ов эти индексы также пригодятся.

Не совсем понятно, что значит *"сравнить значения N подряд идущих строк"*. Вам нужно N предыдущих строк разложить по столбцам?

```
select
    id, value,
    prev = lag(value) over (order by id),
    prev2 = lag(value, 2) over (order by id),
    prev3 = lag(value, 3) over (order by id),
    prev4 = lag(value, 4) over (order by id)
from data

select
    d.id, d.value,
    prev = d_lag.value,
    prev2 = d_lag2.value,
    prev3 = d_lag3.value,
    prev4 = d_lag4.value
from data d
    left join data d_lag on d_lag.id = d.id - 1
    left join data d_lag2 on d_lag2.id = d.id - 2
    left join data d_lag3 on d_lag3.id = d.id - 3
    left join data d_lag4 on d_lag4.id = d.id - 4
```

Или нужно скользящее среднее по N предыдущим строкам?

```
select
    d.id,
    [ma20(-1)] = avg(d.value) over (order by d.id rows between 20 preceding and 1 preceding)
    [ma20(0)] = avg(d.value) over (order by d.id rows between 19 preceding and current row),
from data d

select
    d.id,
    [ma20(-1)] = [s-1].ma20,
    [ma20(0)] = s0.ma20 
from data d
    cross apply (
        select ma20 = avg(d2.value)
        from data d2
        where d2.id between d.id - 19 and d.id
    ) s0
    cross apply (
        select ma20 = avg(d2.value)
        from data d2
        where d2.id between d.id - 20 and d.id - 1
    ) [s-1]
```

Можете попробовать эти запросы на своих данных. На тестовых данных в 100 тыс. строк время исполнения запросов для двух методов (windowed и `join`) у меня получалось сравнимо, только последний запрос выигрывал по времени за счёт параллелелизма, но IO всюду в пользу windowed версий (в случае со скользящим средним - значительно). Вообще по IO все эти windowed запросы сравнимы с простым `select id, value from data`.

Поскольку оконные функции экономнее по IO, подход с их использованием может быть предпочтительнее в случаях, когда IO является узким местом (например, в системах с большим количеством одновременно работающих пользователей). В иных случаях между `join` и windowed следует, вероятно, предпочесть то, что работает быстрее на конкретных данных.